# Need advice about venue for publication

Tags: machine-learning, modal-logic

I have a new article where I propose a logical theory of machine learning (instead of statistical one). In particular, I propose a modal logic to express loss criteria, and show that large number of learning algorithms (from k-NN to K Means, from SVM to Naive Bayes) have loss criteria, which can be formulated in this logic. Also, I show that all procedures of these learners may be expressed in similar terms.
Can somebody suggest where may I publish this text? (May be, I need to add that I am not associated with any University)

Comment: Try AAAI, IJCAI and related conferences.

Comment: @BartoszBednarczyk   Thank you . It appears, it is too late already for this year for both conferences. Are there conferences which would not require travel? Are there journals which publish this stuff?

Comment: I do not know about conferences that do not require traveling. But most of them are online these days.  JAIR is a very reputable journal and people from the description logic community publish there

Comment: @BartoszBednarczyk I have no doubt it is reputable! I am looking for something which publishes abstract papers, not applied. The papers in JAIR seem applied.  What about "Artificial Intelligence"? Would they publish such an abstract paper?

Comment: No idea. But notice that many works submitted to JAIR are not applied (see e.g. the description logics papers).

Comment: Thank you,@BartoszBednarczyk

Comment: A page that I find useful to check upcoming conferences in theoretical computer science (some more AI oriented may be missing so it may not be optimal for you but it can help): http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Miki.Hermann/conf.html

Comment: @holf Do you think that such a paper (29 pages) is more suitable for a conference than a journal?

Comment: I read Bartosz comment and thought you were only looking for conference, my bad. 29 pages is too long for conferences but sometimes you can fit the story in the pages limit while leaving some proofs in the appendix. For journal, AI seems indeed a good choice.

Comment: Thank you, @holf